# Syncing ms Sql databases with AWS

Tags: sql-server, database, amazon-web-services, synchronization, cloud

I'm researching the differences between AWS and Azure for my company. We going to make an web-based application. Which is going to be across 3 regions, each region needs to have a **MS SQL** database.

But I can't figure how to do the following with AWS: the databases need to sync between each region (2 way). So the data stays the same on every Database.

Why we want this? For example a customer* from Eu adds a record to the database. Now this database needs to sync with the other regions. Resulting that a customer form the region US can see the added records. (*Customers can add products to the database)

Do you guys have any idea how we can achieve this?

*it's a requirement to use Ms SQL.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using SQL on EC2 instances then the only way to achieve multi-region, multi-master for MS SQL Server is to use Peer-to-Peer Transactional Replication, however it doesn't protect against individual row conflicts.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151196.aspx

This isn't a feature of AWS RDS for MS SQL, however there is another product for multi-region replication that's available on the AWS marketplace, but it only works for read replicas.

http://cloudbasic.net/aws/rds/alwayson/

Comment: Thanks for your reply, gonna look into it

Answer (score -1):

At present AWS doesn't support read replicas for SQL server RDS databases.
However replication between AWS RDS sql server databases can be done using DMS (database migration service). Refer below link for more details

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/introducing-ongoing-replication-from-amazon-rds-for-sql-server-using-aws-database-migration-service/